# How to quickly check RMI registry?

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

I'm trying to implement the Raft Consensus Algorithm for a Distributed System project.

I need some very quickly way to know if a server A is reachable from a server B AND A's Distributed System is up. In other words, it could happen that the A is reachable by B but the A's cloud system isn't up yet. So I think that `InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout);` isn't enough.

Since each server's stub is renamed as the server's name, I thought to get the server's registry and then check if there exists a stub with the same name of the server: if it's not the case, then skip to the next server, otherwise execute the `lookup` (which can take a looong time). This is part of the code:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Getting "+clusterElement.getId()+"'s registry");
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(clusterElement.getAddress());
    System.out.println("Checking contains:");
    if(!Arrays.asList(registry.list()).contains(clusterElement.getId())) {
        System.out.println("Server "+clusterElement.getId()+" not bound (maybe down?)!");
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("Looking up "+clusterElement.getId()+"'s stub");
    ServerInterface stub = (ServerInterface) registry.lookup(clusterElement.getId());
    System.out.println("Asking vote to "+clusterElement.getId());
    //here methods are called on stub (exploiting costum SocketFactory)
} catch (NoSuchObjectException | java.rmi.ConnectException | java.rmi.ConnectIOException e){
    System.err.println("Candidate "+serverRMI.id+" cannot request vote to "+clusterElement.getId()+" because not reachable");
} catch (UnmarshalException e) {
    System.err.println("Candidate " + serverRMI.id + " timeout requesting vote to " + clusterElement.getId());
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NotBoundException e) {
   System.out.println("Candidate "+serverRMI.id+" NotBound "+clusterElement.getId());
}
```

Now the problem is that the server gets stuck on the `contains()` line, since the message `Checking contains` is printed while `Looking up...` isn't.

Why this happens? There is any way to speed up the process? This algorithm is **FULL** of timeouts, so any suggestion would be really appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
After trying every possible VM property about RMI's timeouts, like:
`-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=1 -Dsun.rmi.transport.proxy.connectTimeout=1 -Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout=1`
I didn't see any difference at all, even if the an exception should have been thrown at every RMI operation (since each timeout is set to 1 ms!).

The only solution that I found out for this problem is to use this `RMISocketFactory` reimplementation:

```
final int timeoutMillis = 100;            
RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory( new RMISocketFactory()
            {
                public Socket createSocket( String host, int port )
                        throws IOException
                {
                    Socket socket = new Socket();
                    socket.setSoTimeout(timeoutMillis);
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeoutMillis);
                    return socket;
                }

                public ServerSocket createServerSocket( int port )
                        throws IOException
                {
                    return new ServerSocket( port );
                }
            } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets stuck in `Registry.list().` It will time out eventually.

You'd be better off just calling `lookup()` without this prior step, which doesn't add any value, and investigating all the timeout options mentioned in the two properties pages linked from the RMI Home Page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think that the java doc about the RMI property is a totally mess. Anyway, I updated the original question including the SocketFactory that I'm using to timeout stub's method calls. Do you think that this timeout is used for `loookup` operation too?

Comment: Ok, through the documentation I found this three intersting properties:
`sun.rmi.transport.proxy.connectTimeout`: it seems the one that I'm looking for, since it's the timeout about creating a socket. The part that I'm not understanding is the one about HTTP.
`sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout`: this could be too, but I don't think so since the server is reachable and so TCP handshake is possible.

`sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout`: definitely not since it reguards methods invocation

Comment: `list()` and `lookup()` *are* remote methods. I would set *all* the timeouts.

Comment: I know that this is a CLASSIC comment, but they don't seem to take effect at all :( Even if I use:
-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=1
-Dsun.rmi.transport.proxy.connectTimeout=1
-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout=1
I don't see any exception raised (though I'm testing the local host version, it would take longer than one millisecond!)...And I'm still using the SocketFactory too

Comment: You need to set those properties before executing any RMI methods,

Comment: I'm setting them as JVM arguments when calling `java` commands...I think that's the best that I can do :D

Comment: Anyway I don't get the difference between the `SocketFactory` timeout features and the `responseTimeout`: which one "prevails" on the other? By what I understand I have to set both, but I don't totally get with which criteria.

Comment: Look at my solution (in UPDATE section). What do you think about? Why it is the only solution that works in your opinion?

Comment: connectTimeout times out the connect attempt: readTimeout operates at the server; responseTimeout operates at the client; proxyTimeout operates when the client is using HTTP tunneling; etc. This is all documented. The 1ms timeouts you are setting are absurdly short and may have been lengthened by RMI.